# Stream extraction within if/else

Tags: c++, error-handling, iostream, runtime-error

Assuming the stream extraction won't fail, will this

```
if( !(stream >> token) )
    throw runtime_error( "Unexpected end of recipe." );
else if( token == "something" )
    // do something
else
    throw runtime_error( "Unknown token" );
```

Work like this

```
if( !(stream >> token) )
    throw std::runtime_error( "Unexpected end of recipe." );

if( token == "something" )
    // do something
else
    throw std::runtime_error( "Unknown token" );
```

(stream = std::stringstream and token = std::string)
And the expected result being `token` contains the next ... token... from the stream?
Is there a better way to handle errors? Like `cerr << "error whatever" << endl; exit();` or something, or is my `std::runtime_error` good enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the logic is exactly the same.

And I wouldn't ever call exit() - at least in your code the exception can be caught by some other code instead of just killing the app. You never know if you will use this code inside a larger application sometime in the future so it's better to keep your options open ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your assumptions are correct, the two snippets will act the same.

Exceptions is the standard way of handling unexpected conditions in C++ so I would not recommend to use another way of handling the error, unless this error is expected to happen in common cases. If that is the case, I would suggest some kind of return value notification on you function instead.